# Replacing text with sed containing whitespace in variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I try to replace some text within a text file. In my script I have store the text to find and to replace within two variables:

```
$currentProductName='hello'
$configProductName='byebye'
```

The replacing is done with this line:

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/$currentProductName/$configProductName/g' "$projectFile"
```

Everything works fine until any of my variables are containing whitespaces. If the `$configProductName` is set to `hello world` the `sed`command does not work as expected.

I´ve already tried this but it doesn't work, too:

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/"$currentProductName"/"$configProductName"/g' "$projectFile"
sed -i'.bak' 's/\$currentProductName/\$configProductName/g' "$projectFile"
```

How do I must change the line to work as expected?

Comment: are you sure `sed -i'.bak' 's/$currentProductName/$configProductName/g'` works?

Comment: yes it works ... running on macOS

Comment: well, as far as I know, bash will not interpret string within single quotes, so not sure how it works for you... strange indeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To preserve the spaces, you need to double-quote the variable and wrap it over once again with single quotes. This way you have control over which variables prefixed with `$` needs to be expanded.

```
configProductName='hello world'
```

Use the `sed` operation just as below and add the `-i` flag once you find it working as expected.

```
sed 's/$currentProductName/'"$configProductName"'/g' file
hello world='hello'
$configProductName='byebye'
```

Comment: this has not been working for me at all on el6 distros, using sed on the cli.  im still plagued on this. `sed: -e expression #1, char x: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @blamb: I verified this to be working. Please take caution on the usage of quotes and make sure you've set the `configProductName` variable with a proper value